Mars 3 Pro Plate refuses to go up in certain files. What could be going on?
I bought a Mars 3 Pro in February, and been printing mostly successful files, all while learning the ropes of 3D modeling, supporting and slicing. For the slice I use CHITUBOXPro V1.4.1.
Since last month, when I disassembled the printer and cleaned the tank screws holes, it has been getting stuck in some prints, where it lowers the plate for the first layer, cures it and simply refuses to lift it further even when I cancel the print and try lift it thru the controls. Only way to get the plate up is manually lift it or restart the printer and lifts like usual.
I've made sure the lift motor is getting enough power, and the plate is completely leveled each time, so I think it's a slice corruption issue, since only about 40% of the prints fail.
What can I check in my CHITU so I can make sure there are no corrupt slices which might be causing this issue?
I would really appreciate any help. :(

Hi Sir Jon, please share the initial code of your gcode print, this lines contains M107, M190, M109, G90, G82 and G28 or G29.

Hiya! Thanks for the reply. :)
The current lines for the start of the print are:
G21;
G90;
M106 S0;
G28 Z0;

Please add the code to your question, be sure to add the lines up to the lines where the printer starts to print (more settings lines).

I've read your question again, and some times the reset is the best solution when the PCB control has a bug, I had the same issue on one of my printers, the printer keeps some Z height and XY positions, seems to be homming is preloaded; with reset allows to flush some bugged control settings. The solution to this is replacing the control board, may be a electrical discarge (ESD) could compromise the board control integrity

Thanks for the info. I'm completely new to 3D printing and knowing a bit more is always welcome.
The electrical discharge sounds plausible, since I had some issues with the outlet the printer is connected to a while back. I will try to test the board in case there might be some damage and replace it in case there is. Thanks a ton! :D
